# Rails 3.2 sunspot_rails and sunspot_solr wont get started on Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sunspot, sunspot-rails, sunspot-solr

Edit: Downloaded the zip and installed it manually, now everything works fine.

---

Unfortunately it seems to be impossible to set up Sunspot and Solr on Windows. Running rake sunspot:solr:run works fine, however, when trying to reindex or if on server development mode and perform the search method, you get the exception "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. - connect(2)". I installed sunspot_rails and sunspot_solr today, so it should be the latest versions. Updated java as well today to 1.7.0_05. Now, [here](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/issues/163) some people get it working by changing line 104 in server.rb from exec(Shellwords.shelljoin(command)) to system(Shellwords.shelljoin(command)), but this doesn't work for me either. I don't really see any possible solution left to try. Does anybody have an idea how to get it work on windows 7? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This is possibly from the port. Can you check sunspot.yml configuration and the real port Sunspot is running on? You should see it when you run Sunspot.

I had similar issue and used to start/stop it, change the port from 8981 to 8982 and it worked.